# C#, default parameter value for an IntPtr

Tags: c#, intptr, default-parameters

I'd like to use a default parameter value of [`IntPtr.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx) in a function that takes an `IntPtr` as an argument. This is not possible as `IntPtr.Zero` is not a compile time constant.

Is there any way I can do what I want?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Somewhat unintuitive, to put it mildly, you get it by using the *new* operator:

```
    void Foo(IntPtr arg = new IntPtr()) { 
    }
```

That was for fun, you probably enjoy this one better:

```
    void Foo(IntPtr arg = default(IntPtr)) { 
    }
```

Comment: Darn, I had a hunch that "default" might work, but no compiler nearby to check - so played it safe. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since `IntPtr` is a struct, you could use Nullable-of-T?

```
static void SomeMethod(IntPtr? ptr = null) {
    var actualPtr = ptr ?? IntPtr.Zero;
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that using only `default` works as well:

```
void Foo(IntPtr arg = default) 
{ 
}
```